# How to get the another model data in the virtual field getter function | mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I am working on a MERN stack project where A user can perform CRUD operations on Goals. I use mongoose for object modeling. I want to create a [virtual field](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html) named **stepAvg** to find out some information about each goal by using the step model.

***Relationship information***

Each user has many goals.

Each goal has many steps.

**GoalModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const StepModel = require("./StepModel");

const GoalSchema = new Schema({
    category: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Category", required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    startDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    completionDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    commitment: { type: String, required: true },
    obstacle: { type: String, default: null },
    celebration: { type: String, default: null },
    user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    steps: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Step"}],
}, {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
}, {timestamps: true});

GoalSchema.virtual('stepAvg').get(async function() {
    let steps = await StepModel.find({ goal: this.id }); 
    // if I console steps it return the data correctly.
    let totalSteps = steps.length;
    if (totalSteps) {
        let completedSteps = steps.filter(function(step) {
            return step.isCompleted;
        }).length;
        let avg = ( completedSteps / totalSteps) * 100;
        return avg;
    }
    return 0;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Goal", GoalSchema);
```

As you can see I create a virtual field **stepAvg** but every time it gives me the empty object. It actually returns the promise.

Postman screenshot
[image: Postman screenshot]